# function pointer vs Fn trait object

Tags: function, rust, closures, traits, trait-objects

```
fn do_twice(f: fn(i32) -> i32, arg: i32) -> i32 { // definition
    f(arg) + f(arg)
}

do_twice(|x| x + 1, 5) // call
```

This function accepts both, closures and function pointers. It takes a function pointer as parameter type.

When should I prefer this over using a trait object, like `&dyn Fn(i32) -> i32` or `Box<dyn Fn(i32)-> i32>` instead of `fn`

```
fn do_twice(f: &dyn Fn(i32) -> i32, arg: i32) -> i32 { // definition
    f(arg) + f(arg)
}

do_twice(&|x| x + 1, 5) // call
```

or

```
fn do_twice(f: Box<dyn Fn(i32) -> i32>, arg: i32) -> i32 { // definition
    f(arg) + f(arg)
}
```

Comment: Thanks that did clarify my query.
fn type parameters can only accept closures that do not capture environment
So, should use trait object when no such constraint is intended

Comment: For reference (in addition to the answers): [RFC 1558](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1558-closure-to-fn-coercion.md) proposed to automatically coerce closures that don't capture their environment to fn pointers. Thanks to this RFC, your example works (maybe unexpectedly).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`fn` type is a bare function pointer (https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.fn.html).

It won't work with the closure that captures environment and it cannot be implemented manually for your fancy type (like `impl Fn for MySuperType`)

So the only reason why your examples working is the fact that it's oversimplified!

if you make it just a bit more complicated, it will fail https://gist.github.com/rust-play/2167e73325daa1e2a179505209405917

Answer (score 14):

> When should I prefer this over using a trait object

Trait objects are not the only other option. As @DarthKotik pointed out, accepting a `fn` pointer will not permit closures that capture their environment, but you can just use a normal type parameter, bounded by `Fn` to accept both functions and closures, without needing to box anything:

```
fn do_twice<F>(f: F, arg: i32) -> i32 
where
    F: Fn(i32) -> i32
{
    f(arg) + f(arg)
}
```

Or, equivalently, but avoiding an extra type variable:

```
fn do_twice(f: impl Fn(i32) -> i32, arg: i32) -> i32 {
    f(arg) + f(arg)
}
```